# Get values from array and using the values in a program

Tags: c#

I have the code below which has created 2 arrays of integers from an input text file, I am trying to use the values from the 2 arrays to read a database using a stored procedure but I am getting this error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Error is occuring when I run and debug program when it tries to assign
`tests[x] = testId;` in the code.

```
//read the error file
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\AccessError.txt"))
    try
    {
        int testId = 0;
        int eventId = 0;
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //split the line
            string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { "Event" },   StringSplitOptions.None);

            //get valid integers
            int[] tests = GetInts(parts[0].Split(' ', '\'')).ToArray();
            int[] events = GetInts(parts[1].Split(' ', '\'')).ToArray();

            foreach (int x in tests)
            {
                tests[x] = testId;
            }
            foreach (int y in events)
            {
                events[y] = eventId;
            }
            //stored proc to call database
            SybaseAccess.GetPlans(aseConn, testId, eventId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Uwe Keim Hi, I edited this question could you release the hold on this please.

Comment: @juharr Hi, I edited this question could you release the hold on this please.

Comment: What is it that you expect `tests[x] = testId;` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is probably just what's going wrong: You're trying to access the array at an index that doesn't exist.

Let's say that you've parsed the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 from the line. These numbers are stored in the `tests` array, it has five elements. In this case the first four array accesses will work, but the fifth will fail, because the array has the indices 0,1,2,3,4

You should check if the numbers in `tests` don't exceed the length of the array.

Moreover I don't understand what exactly you are doing. You are parsing an array of numbers from a line ? And then you overwrite each of these numbers by replacing it with the testId ? That's rather complicated. If you want to have an array that contains n-times the testId as an integer, why not create that directly ?